# Set version number in package.json

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to add a grunt task that accepts a version number. This version number will then be set in the `package.json` file. I have found grunt-bump, which bumps the version number, but I would like to set the version number to a known value, that will come from the build server.

Grunt task:

```
grunt.registerTask('setversion', function() {
  // Something to go here to update the version number.
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "scoreboard",
  "version": "0.2",
  ...
}
```

Anyone got any idea's?

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like:

```
  grunt.registerTask('setversion', function(arg1) {
       console.log("Attempting to update version to "+arg1);
       var parsedJson= grunt.file.readJSON("package.json");//read in the current
       parsedJson["version"] = arg1; //set the top level version field to arg1
       grunt.file.write("package.json", JSON.stringify(parsedJson, null, 2));
    });
```

add in some error checking etc.. make sure package.json is writable and execute with `grunt setversion:newVersion` e.g.:  `grunt setversion:0.3`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, but it turned out to be a lot more straightforward. I am using TeamCity, so I ran an NPM task with the following command, where `%system.build.number%` follows the pattern `n.n.n`, e.g.: `0.1.6`.

```
--no-git-tag-version version %system.build.number%
```